# Avoiding browser popup for 401

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, basic-authentication

I'm developing REST service using Jersey with BASIC auth, everything work fine....
Client side I want use my own login form and avoid the ugly default browser form.
Unfortunately when the browser receive 401 the default form appear to ruin my fancy login form.

Googling around I found this blog http://loudvchar.blogspot.ca/2010/11/avoiding-browser-popup-for-401.html that have a workaround but it utilize spring instead of Jersey.

Basically the advice is to change "WWW-Authenticate:Basic" with ""WWW-Authenticate:xBasic"  in the WWW-Authenticate header so the browswer will disable the pop up.

The question is, how can I achieve this  in Jersey or in some tomcat  web.xml config.
Another solution could be intercept the 401 response and change it in some other custom code, but I don't know how to make it.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

Comment: Why do you bother? Jersey is a REST framework not primary targeted at browsers.

Comment: Does the REST service use HTTP Basic authentication? I tend to agree with @Michael-O, here.

Comment: After some evaluations I switched definitely with default browser login... actually is more compliant with REST and BASIC auth.